AWS Warm pool | Warmed:Running instances are serving traffic instead of waiting for a scale out event
I have two instances under auto scaling group with an internal ALB in front.
I am trying to launch warm pool with instances in a Running state.
When checking target group for the ALB, it only shows two targets that are not from the warm pool, however, when checking my application, running in containers, I can see all 4 instances.
I don't want these containers to serve traffic just yet and get more logs and what not.

What do you mean by "when checking my application, running in containers, I can see all 4 instances"? Are you saying that all 4 instances are processing traffic, or that they simply exist?

Ty for your reply, it simply exists, it doesn't spit out any logs nor accept traffic.
But it's still weird as to why the instances that are supposed to be Warmed are showing up as registered in my app.

What does the EC2 console show as the state of the 'warm' instances? Are they Running or Stopped?

From Warm pools for Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling - Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling:

You can keep instances in the warm pool in one of three states: Stopped, Running, or Hibernated. Keeping instances in a Stopped state is an effective way to minimize costs. With stopped instances, you pay only for the volumes that you use and the Elastic IP addresses attached to the instances.
Alternatively, you can keep instances in a Hibernated state to stop instances without deleting their memory contents (RAM). When an instance is hibernated, this signals the operating system to save the contents of your RAM to your Amazon EBS root volume. When the instance is started again, the root volume is restored to its previous state and the RAM contents are reloaded. While the instances are in hibernation, you pay only for the EBS volumes, including storage for the RAM contents, and the Elastic IP addresses attached to the instances.
Keeping instances in a Running state inside the warm pool is also possible, but is highly discouraged to avoid incurring unnecessary charges. When instances are stopped or hibernated, you are saving the cost of the instances themselves. You pay for the instances only when they are running.

It sounds like your 'warm' instances are in a Running state. You should check the configuration of Warm pool instance state on the warm pool. The default is Stopped. Perhaps they launch in a Running state, but change to Stopped after a period of non-use?

Thanks for the thorough answer, John.
The instances are in the Warmed:Running state and it's not about the cost, it's about having the warmed instances stand by for a scale event.
But my app can register the warmed instances.
The confusing part is that I can't diff the warmed ec2 from the regular ones when listing or doing other operations...

I guess the only difference is that they aren't receiving traffic. In fact, they might even appear the same when they are Stopped/Hibernated.

As pointed out by others and John above, If the instances are in Warmed:Running state, it will still appear in your containers as an application since the container is running and independent of the AWS Warm pool state. If you want them to not appear in the containers, might as well change the warm pool configurations to Stopped state.
